# Notepad++: Search and Replace with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of entries in Notepad++ (amongst other text mixed in), where I'm trying to remove the dash symbol in-between any 2 numbers.

**I have data like this:**

```
text text this is text here
234-5678
this is more text here 
123-4585 this is more text here
or text is here too 583-5974
```

**Desired Results:**

```
text text this is text here
2345678
this is more text here 
1234585 this is more text here
or text is here too 5835974
```

**I've tried:**

```
Find: [0-9]-[0-9] (which works to find the (#)(dash)(#)
Replace: $0, $1, \1, ^$0, "$0", etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex.

```
(?<=\d)-(?=\d)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you, works perfectly. For other users, this is the FIND expression you want, then the REPLACE text would just be blank (removes dashes). Thank you edi_allen

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your method of:

```
Find: [0-9]-[0-9] (which works to find the (#)(dash)(#)
Replace: $0, $1, \1, ^$0, "$0", etc.
```

Is that `$0` or `$1` etc refer to captured groups while your find regex doesn't have any. It would have worked if you did:

```
Find: ([0-9])-([0-9])
Replace: $1$2
```

`$1` would contain the first digit and `$2` the second.

Of course now, using lookarounds like in [edi_allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19714786/1578604) (`(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind and `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead) also work and avoids you the trouble of using backreferences (the `$1` and `$2`).

`$0` contains the whole match. `$1` contains the first captured group and `$2` contains the second captured group.