# Add spaces around brackets in multiple files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: search, replace, sublimetext3, code-formatting

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a search and replace in Sublime Text 3 to add spaces around brackets in multiple files.

For example, I need to convert this in multiple files:

```
$var = function($par1, $par2);
```

to:

```
$var = function( $par1, $par2 );
```

Any ideas? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Regex expressions in find and replace. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525939/difficulties-with-adding-spaces-around-equal-signs-using-regular-expressions-wit

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling around, I managed to come up with a regex to add spaces around brackets:

```
Find: \((.*?)\)
Replace: ( $1 )
```

**UPDATE:** The following regex is more precise because it matches `($var)` but not `( $var )` nor `()`:

```
Find: \((?!\s)([^()]+)(?<!\s)\)
Replace: ( $1 )
```